# Upgrading GuzzleHttp v5 to v6

Tags: guzzle

The following code fragment works in GuzzleHttp v5.

```
$response = $client->post(
    $uri,
    [
        'headers' => ['Cookie' => 'JSESSIONID=' . $sessionId],
        'body'    => ['Filedata' => fopen($filename, 'r')],
    ]
);
```

The contents of the file specified in $filename are sent to the URI as the variable 'Filedata'.

The specification for the upload is:

```
http://yourserver.com/services/create?Filedata=<multipart/form-data encoded file>...
```

The file MUST be sent as 'Filedata'. How should this be coded for GuzzleHttp v6?

As far as I can see GuzzleHttp v6 does not allow this but I've only been trying for a day or two and don't have any more time to research it myself as the application has to be delivered on Monday.

Any ideas?

I'll leave it as v5 for now but this is just ducking the question.

Comment: Are you asking about how to formulate the request? Are you attempting to stream the file, or send it all in one shot? Is the Uri you are attempting to post your file too? If so, why is information that can be found within the Content-Type header being placed within the Uri and not within the header?

Comment: It's done this way because the specification of the server receiving the data requires it this way, everything for this request goes in the URI including the jsessionid which also goes in the header as shown. The code for Guzzle v5 is trivial as shown above but v6 has changed all that and it is no longer immediately obvious how this request should be formulated. So, the question is how should the above code fragment be coded for Guzzle v6? For Monday's demo I've used Guzzle v5 but it will need to be changed sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you find the answer it is, of course, obvious. The following code is the solution:

```
$response = $client->post(
    $uri,
    [
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name'     => 'Filedata',
                'contents' => open($filename, 'r'),
            ]
        ],
        'headers' => ['Cookie' => 'JSESSIONID=' . $sessionId],
    ]
);
```

Thanks to Shaun Bramley for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I was on the fence w/ multipart given the flow control through 5.3.  Glad I was able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

My original questions were to provide additional context for your particular use case.

For your particular use case, the primary issue will be that the 'body' request option no longer accepts arrays.  Reference: [Client::requestAsync](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php#L107) will call `client::invalidBody()` if `is_array()` is true.

The simplest way for you to proceed, should be as fol:

```
$response = $client->post(
    $uri,
    [
        'headers' => ['Cookie' => 'JSESSIONID=' . $sessionId],
        'form_params'    => ['Filedata' => fopen($filename, 'r')],
    ]
);
```

By default Guzzle 5.3 treated body params that were passed in as arrays as PostBody.  Which meant that the array index and value were eventually urlencoded as a string using `http_build_query`.

Depending upon your particular use case (the length of time your client maintains its sessions) you might also want to look into using the CookieJar.  Links: [Using Cookies](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#cookies) and [CookieJar](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Cookie/CookieJar.php) for reference.

Comment: Many thanks for this. My ignorance of Guzzle is painfully obvious. I will give this a try once the demonstration has been completed and mark the answer once I have verified that it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution did not appear to work. The data sent to the server in the Filedata variable was empty. I used a small file to avoid any timeout constraints. It seems as though the file stream was not read when creating the request.